# Accessing Array Elements in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly

I'm having an issue with a code for an assignment. It's a function that's referenced to calculate the numbers in an array to get the average. It's passed to the function below. I'm just having trouble getting the actual values from the array, and am having a horrible time trying to find information on array usage in assembly. It looks like I'm just getting the reference/address data. Help????

**Some of the code below is taken from notes I took during class, and the rest is me trying to fill in the blanks. It's probably awful to follow, so sorry in advance.

```
.586             

.MODEL FLAT, C 

.STACK 
.DATA 

.CODE 

AverageFunc PROC

NoOfElemenstsDW EQU 08 ArrayAddrStartPtr EQU 12

push ebp

mov ebp, esp

push edi

push ecx

mov ecx, [ebp + NoOfElemenstsDW ] 

mov edi, [ebp + ArrayAddrStartPtr]

sub ebx, ebx ;set ebx to 0

sub eax, eax ;set eax to 0

sub edx, edx ;must set to 0 to get accurate division

L1:

add eax, [edi] ;add value to total

inc edi ;go to next point in the array

add ebx, 1 ;add 1 to the counter

cmp ebx, ecx ;compare ecx and ebx

jl L1 ;If ebx < ecx, loop again

div ecx ;divide sum by total numbers

pop ecx

pop edi

pop ebp

ret

AverageFunc ENDP

END
```

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're calling this function (i.e. what you're passing as the actual parameters).

Answer (score 0):

If your AverageFunc is supposed to return EAX only then you still have to push and pop EDX.

These 2 don't go together

```
add eax, [edi] ;add value to total
inc edi ;go to next point in the array
```

Since EDI points to a double word you need to raise EDI by 4 in stead of 1.

Also the addition will soon overflow. Solve it with

```
add eax,[edi]
adc edx,0
```

As a precaution put a suitable `jecxz` right before the L1 label.

ps **It's probably awful to follow** Don't think like that. It's one of the better codes I've seen on this forum.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out and see if it fixes the problem. We just moved to calling procedures from separate .asm files using c++ (rather than just having embedded code), and I'm still getting used to using the stack as well, so it's got me all mixed up.